# Why would Worf take part in a dishonourable scheme?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9

In this episode of DS9 (S05E03), Quark takes part in a Klingon duel to the death.  Knowing that he has no chance to defeat Grilka's bodyguard Thopok, Quark uses

> "a special device implemented by Dax [by which] Worf is able to control Quark's
>   body movements from an adjacent holosuite"

**Why would Worf agree to take part in such a dishonourable venture?**

In the very same episode he:

> proposes he and Dax should get married, because it's customary after the mating ritual

Which implies he does very strongly value Klingon traditions.

I feel like this is episode's plot was constructed to follow a classic romantic comedy/tragedy theme, but with sloppy disregard for Worf's character

Answer (score 7):

Large elements of this story emulate the classic Cyrano de Bergerac, with Worf playing the part of Cyrano, Grilka as Roxanne and Quark as Christian, the man who attempts to trick Roxanne into loving Christian. As with that story, he reasons that since he himself is not able to woo Roxanne (due to his own position, in Worf's case) he can at least assist his friend into winning the heart of the fair Roxanne.

Worf ultimately agrees to take part in the rather shady business of using Quark as a meat puppet for a few reasons.

- Thopok is not acting honourably. Worf dislikes those who prey on the weak.
- It's **Worf's damn fault that Quark is in the situation in the first place**. If he'd just left well enough alone, she'd have left the station days before. Quark is going to die without his intervention.

> **WORF:** *No one will stop Thopok. Dax and I will not even be allowed to attend.*
>
> **QUARK:** *So my choices are... to not show up, be branded a coward and lose Grilka... or die.*

- Jadzia is clearly pressuring him into it.
- The whole thing is playing out like Worf's holonovels about Kahless. He's being swept up in the whole thing without really spotting the likely consequences.

> **WORF:** *I do not believe the lengths I am going to for that Ferengi. I am practically giving him Grilka.*

- If Worf/Quark can win the fight, then no-one needs to die. A win-win for all concerned.

> **GRILKA:** *Thopok, your honor is satisfied. I return your weapon and discharge you from my House.*

Comment: I guess this is a tangential discussion - but is Thopok acting dishonourably?  Yes Quark is no match for him, but if he wants Quark out of Grillka's life, this is the valid Klingon path to take, no?

Comment: @Francis - My take was that he's acting within the *technical* bounds of Klingon honour, but that he's also facing off in a fight that he knows he can't lose (which Worf would see as dishonourable).

Comment: are there other options are available to Thopok?

Comment: @Francis - That's a toughie. It seems like the most honourable thing to do would be to do his job and not get involved in his Mistress' private affairs.

Answer (score 2):

Worf has always been shown to have his own vision of what honor truly means, that is not always necessarily in line with traditional cultural Klingon views (though often is) - and often goes *against* Klingon politics. He has also been shown to occasionally accept a more 'human' pragmatist's path to solving some problems. So right off the bat we can presume that Worf has a pre-existing disposition to not be honorable 'by the book', as it were. On top of which Jadzia, who Worf is clearly attracted to, is pressuring him to help.

It's not difficult to justify his actions as honorable, especially when one takes into consideration his more pragmatic 'human' moments; helping a comrade out of a situation where his only options are death, or humiliation. Additionally, as laid out in the other answer, Quark is IN this situation due to Worf in the first place.

I think it's also worth noting that if Quark were a Klingon, I think Worf would be far LESS willing to help if it were requested; a Klingon warrior could give Thopok a good fight and WOULD be bound by Klingon honor, but Quark stands no chance, and everyone involved knows it, on top of which he's not even part of that culture.

Now, all of the above might seem to be in conflict with the OTHER thing Worf does in this episode that you mentioned, for no reason other than 'tradition demands', but I don't think so. With the above, Worf has his own experiences to rely on, his own history among both Klingons and humans to tell him that the honorable path isn't always the one defined by tradition. But where romance is concerned, Worf has very little experience. It's not surprising or out of character that when presented with a new situation he has very little experience with, he would 'fall back' to traditional Klingon values for lack of anything else.